# Return True|False from a function in a class in python

Tags: python, class, function, boolean, return

I can't get the return value True|False from a function.
What Am I doing wrong?

The script looks roughly like that.

```
class getLogs:

    IAM=getpass.getuser()
    SRC_LOG_DIR='/server/log/session/'
    DST_LOG_DIR="/home/${IAM}/LOGS/"

    def __init__(self):

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument("-S","--sessId", type=int, help="The SessionId of the logs to retreive for.")
        args = parser.parse_args()



        if not args.sessId:
            args.sessId = 'ns'
            os.system('clear')
            print ('\tNo sessid was set.')
            print ('\tTip: you can see what options you have by running "{} -h"'.format(__file__))            

        self.getSessID(args.sessId)

        if self.getSessID:
            print('\tI will get the logfiles for session ID "{}".'.format(self.sessId))            
            #Do something else

    def getSessID(self, sessId):

        if sessId == 'ns':
            menu='on'        
            while menu=='on':

                sys.stdout.write("\tPlease give me the sessionid of the logging :")
                sessId = raw_input()
                test = re.match("^[0-9]{5,7}$",sessId)

                if test:
                    menu='off'


                if not test:
                    print('\tError:\n\tSessionID should contain only numbers')
                    print('\tor sessID was not defined.')
                    print('\tor sessID length must be 5 to 7 characters')

        self.sessId = sessId
        return True
```

And what I get from this `print self.getSessID` and from `if self.getSessID` in the constructor function is this `<bound method getLogs.getSessID of <__main__.getLogs instance at 0x7f5aa28e1518>>`

Im sure I am doing something wrong, I haven't understood how to get the value from the return in a function.
Could someone please help me?

Comment: Fix the indentation in the code.

Comment: You have to *call* the method/function...

Comment: You are testing `self.getSessID` without calling it; it'll always be `True` because you have a function object there, not a result.

Comment: Or more precisely, you need to save the return value when you do call it; you are checking that the name `self.getSessId` isn't bound to a false value.

Comment: Don't I call the function here? `self.getSessID(args.sessId)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, it won't be `True`, it'll be a bound method object (which is what he sees when he prints it out)—but it's still _truthy_.

Comment: @user2457193: Yes, you do call the function in that line. But you don't call it in the line `if self.getSessID:`, you just reference the method itself.

Comment: @abarnert: I was keeping things simple. :-) The `if` statement will always match.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah, because `if` only cares about truthiness, not equality (or identity) with `Truth`. We don't need to explain all of that to the OP, but just saying "truthy" instead of `True` is simple enough, and accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the method, then testing if the method exists:

```
self.getSessID(args.sessId)

if self.getSessID:
    print('\tI will get the logfiles for session ID "{}".'.format(self.sessId))
```

You need to store the result and test *that*:

```
session_id = self.getSessID(args.sessId)

if session_id:
    print('\tI will get the logfiles for session ID "{}".'.format(session_id))
```

It could also be that you wanted to test `self.sessId`, which you set in your `self.getSessID()` method.

Comment: Oh guys thank you so much!
No I can finally do some work!